# Pandas Grouper showing TypeError

Tags: python, pandas

I used Pandas Groupby to group data but got

> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

My code:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='W-Sun')).apply(lambda x: " ".join(x['Text']))
```

Then I used:

```
df = df.applymap(str)
```

But got

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Comment: How does your data look like and what is the expected result?

Comment: My data has 2 columns: Date and Text columns. The text column does not contain any numbers yet the typeError insists on the presence of float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#if need convert values to strings
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='W-Sun'))['Text'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x.astype(str)))
```

---

```
#if need remove NaNs and Nones values in Text column
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='W-Sun'))['Text'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x.dropna()))
```

---

```
#if need remove NaNs and Nones values in Text column and cast to str
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='W-Sun'))['Text'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x.astype(str).dropna()))
```